# Get multiple records only using SELECT DISTINCT or similar

Tags: sql, select, distinct, multiple-records

I have records like this:

```
Column1 Column2
A       Blue
A       Blue
B       Red
B       Green
C       Blue
C       Red
```

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` I get this:

```
Column1 Column2
A       Blue
B       Red
B       Green
C       Blue
C       Red
```

What I'd like to get:

```
Column1 Column2
B       Red
B       Green
C       Blue
C       Red
```

So I need to get only multiple records of column1 that have different values on column2.
(I'm joining two tables)

With SELECT DISTINCT, I got closer to what I need, but I can't find a way to exclude records like "A" on column1 that have always the same value on column2...

Comment: What database are you using? MSSQL? MySQL? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE Column1 IN
(SELECT Column1
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Column1
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) > 1
)
```

The `DISTINCT` in `COUNT` ensures that you only get those records where `Column2` has multiple distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work in most systems:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
HAVING COUNT(*)<=1
```

See the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47285/8/0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server....that's not how `DISTINCT` works, `DISTINCT` is applied across the whole list of Columns in the `SELECT` statement, that's why you're getting the output you mentioned. Try using a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` like below...

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM [table_name] 
GROUP BY Column1, Column2 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2 
ORDER BY Column1
```

Comment: this is true of all sql not just mssql; "select distinct" is a row operator (across the whole row)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Query :

```
SELECT Col1,Col2
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
HAVING COUNT(Col1)<=1
```

Comment: This seems to be what was asked for (as do a couple other answers). One minor variation could be simply to use `COUNT(Col1)=1`. There shouldn't be any `<1` counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
select a.Column1 ,count(a.Column1 )
from 
   (select Distinct Column1 ,Column2 
    from Items) a
group by a.Column1 
having Count(a.Column1 ) > 1
```